# Starting an activity from Broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcast, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to launch the Main Activity from a broadcast receiver. Can anyone guide me as to how I can do it? I always get "Process is Bad" message.

Thanks

Comment: What is "the Main Activity"? What is a "Process is Bad" message? If you are getting an error dialog, please use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to get a stack trace and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the emulator  or just Kill the process that will solve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

When using a real device, the only I found to fix this was:

- Uninstall the app through Settings -> Applications.
- Remove the battery from the phone (using the Android "Power off" menu did not work).
- Turn device on again.
- Install the APK again using adb install .

My app didn't show up in the list of processes running on the device (it's a BroadcastReceiver), so I wasn't able to kill that process.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320089/112705) for more detail on what didn't work.