# Unable to launch app com.bell.ship's clock/10024 for broadcast Intent: process is bad

Tags: android, android-logcat

i have created application like to alarm notification , all of working fine at once but after sometime i have found error like that Unable to launch app com.bell.ship's clock/10024 for broadcast Intent: process is bad in logcat .

logcat is shown below.

```
08-10 19:00:24.350: DEBUG/dalvikvm(657): GC freed 2898 objects / 149328 bytes in 205ms
08-10 19:00:24.980: INFO/ActivityManager(64): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.SplashScreen bnds=[3,138][77,217] }
08-10 19:00:25.970: INFO/ActivityManager(64): Displayed activity com.bell.shipclock/.SplashScreen: 833 ms (total 833 ms)
08-10 19:00:31.261: DEBUG/dalvikvm(142): GC freed 114 objects / 5248 bytes in 215ms
08-10 19:00:33.511: INFO/ActivityManager(64): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.Home }
08-10 19:00:33.551: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{44da36f0 com.bell.shipclock/.SplashScreen}
08-10 19:00:34.631: INFO/ActivityManager(64): Displayed activity com.bell.shipclock/.Home: 1043 ms (total 1043 ms)
08-10 19:00:35.000: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:00:35.011: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:01:35.011: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:01:35.031: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:02:35.071: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:02:35.121: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:03:35.060: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:03:35.070: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:04:35.021: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:04:35.031: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:05:27.730: DEBUG/dalvikvm(657): GC freed 8964 objects / 439224 bytes in 260ms
08-10 19:05:35.010: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:05:35.023: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:06:35.051: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:06:35.061: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:07:35.050: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:07:35.061: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:08:35.035: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:08:35.053: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:09:35.071: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:09:35.090: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:10:34.050: DEBUG/dalvikvm(64): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
08-10 19:10:35.050: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:10:35.070: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:11:35.071: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:11:35.090: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:12:15.870: DEBUG/dalvikvm(657): GC freed 12371 objects / 576528 bytes in 3495ms
08-10 19:12:17.961: DEBUG/dalvikvm(64): threadid=15: bogus mon 1+0>0; adjusting
08-10 19:12:35.011: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:12:35.032: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:13:02.470: DEBUG/dalvikvm(64): GC freed 12863 objects / 648880 bytes in 2315ms
08-10 19:13:35.046: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:13:35.061: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
08-10 19:14:35.081: WARN/ActivityManager(64): Unable to launch app com.bell.shipclock/10024 for broadcast Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.bell.shipclock/.AlarmReceive1 (has extras) }: process is bad
08-10 19:14:35.090: WARN/ActivityManager(64): finishReceiver called but none active
```

i am new user of the Android and i never see this error like before.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you are calling `finish()` twice for your splash screen ("Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{44da36f0 com.bell.shipclock/.SplashScreen}"). Clear that up, and perhaps it will fix your other problems.

Comment: calling finish() twice seems to be the root cause here. Others who end up here might find it useful to see this answer about the usage of finish() method of an activity:http://stackoverflow.com/a/11459981/1505341

Answer (score 0):

When using a real device, the only I found to fix this was:

- Uninstall the app through Settings -> Applications.
- Remove the battery from the phone (using the Android "Power off" menu did not work).
- Turn device on again.
- Install the APK again using adb install .

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320089/112705) for more detail on what didn't work.