# Best practices for calling finish() on an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

Most of my activities load dynamic data from a server, and when the page comes back into focus, i reload it anyway. It seems wasteful to keep them around if I'm just going to reload them, so I thought of calling finish() on them if the user navigates away from the page.

Its confusing if some activities you can press the back button to go to and others no because I've called finish() on them, so I was wondering if its bad practice just to call finish() on all activities the user navigates away from? (I have a navigation bar at the bottom of every activity so the back button isnt necessary). Or, is it better practice not to call finish() on any of the activities and just hope they dont slow down the phone and that the OS will take care of garbage collecting them?

I'm new to Android programming and and don't have an Android phone so i'm not sure what is the common/best practice in this situation, or if its just a matter of personal taste.

Also, is it possible to instruct Android to keep a history of activities so that the back button still works, but finish() them when they navigate away so that they're not needlessly taking up resources?

Comment: Just to chime in also as an Android *user* (you said you don't have an Android phone), you mentioned it might not be necessary to use the back button because you have a navigation bar on every activity. I for one *always* use the back button no matter what the interface, just out of sheer habit. Something to keep in mind...good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you may reload all your data on returning to the activity, there is still no point on calling `finish()`.

When activities are hidden, they do not use resources, and are of no real problem. Just leave them as is, and then when the user navigates back, it will reload it as required.

In this state, they can also be garbage collected if required - which is all taken care of by android.

Answer (score 0):

In most circumstances you do not need to (and should not) call finish(); Android takes care of managing the activities for you.

If you need to do cleanup when a user leaves the activity, you can do that sort of thing in the various activity callbacks such as onDestroy().

If you haven't done so already, read [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) in the Android developer guide.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `finish()` unless you're sure that activity won't be executed in a long time. It's better to let Android handle what to do with it. Put your cleaning code in `onPause()` and your loading code in `onResume()`.