# Widget: onUpdate, onReceive - appWidgetManager - not working in v2.3.5 and v3.2.1

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, android-appwidget

I am new to Android applications and hence have a few questions. 
Using the code below, I am trying action on ImageButton. And it would be important to remember that this is a **Widget**, not an Activity.

I searched online for examples on using ImageButton in a Widget and found very little information. However, this working example seems to have problems with different versions of Android.

Now, the code works on old version (2.1-update1) of Android and not in new version of phone(2.3.5) or on Tablet (3.2.1)

- Working - (2.1-update1,  Samsung 5700)
- Not working - (2.3.5, HTC Desire HD )
- Not working - (3.2.1, ASUS)

It seems as if there have been some changes in the API due to which it has stopped working. (My suggestion of a possibility. Not sure about it though.)

LogCat of  2.1-update1

Log:

D/AAAAAA  ( 3408):   ======= onReceive

D/AAAAAA  ( 3408):   ======= onUpdate

Looks like in other versions even functions onUpdate() and onReceive() are not working.

My code: (  Test code... :) )

Could you please look at the code and explain this behaviour.

```
public class A_Org_WidgetActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AAAAAA";

    Button btn;
    TextView txt1;
    ImageButton button; 
    boolean bIcon = true;

    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE = "ConfigureWidget";
    public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "ActionReceiverWidget";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "  ======= onUpdate");

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.hor_bott_4x3);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, ClickOneActivity.class);
        configIntent.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, A_Org_WidgetActivity.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);
        active.putExtra("msg", "Message for Button 1");

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, active, 0);
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageButton06, actionPendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ImageButton07, configPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);

    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // v1.5 fix that doesn't call onDelete Action
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        String msg = "null";

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "  ======= onReceive");

        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID );

            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId } );
            }
        } else {
            // check, if our Action was called
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
                try {
                    msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "  ======= msg = null");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "  Error msg: " + e);
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                Notification noty = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Button 1 clicked",
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                noty.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Notice", msg, contentIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(1, noty);
            }
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }

}
```

And...

My manifest ***.xml

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/red_circle" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name="A_Org_WidgetActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <!--
        <action android:name="com.widget.bla-bla.A_Org_WidgetActivity.ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER" />
    -->
    <!-- Service to perform web API queries -->
    <service android:name="A_Org_WidgetActivity$UpdateService" />

    <!-- this activity will be called, when we fire our self created ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE -->
    <activity android:name="CommonActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.widget.bla-bla.A_Org_WidgetActivity.ACTION_WIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Comment: It may looks a little rediculus, but here found solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253676/how-to-fix-process-is-bad-error-for-an-android-widget

Comment: pr.stas, if you found a solution to your question, you should post it as an answer, and accept it. It's perfectly valid here in SO