# onReceive not entered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing an app which gets the contents of a sms and do something. I registered a receiver in manifest file and give it a very high priority. It works fine on a android 2.3.3 device. but on a android 2.3.7 device it does nothing! seems like the onReceive() is not invoked on the 2.3.7 device. can anybody help me with this? thank you very much!

Comment: Does that mobile have any other app with greater priority?

Comment: Max value you can give is 2147483647

Comment: I have same issue :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377155/widget-onupdate-onreceive-appwidgetmanager-not-work-in-v2-3-5-and-v3-2-1
2.3.5 - not have reaction on broadcast

Comment: it's not my phone so don't know. but i'll try to give my app the highest priority

Comment: so pr.stas you reboot the phone and the problem is gone?

Answer (score 0):

figure it out! the answer is there are some application that can somehow et the broadcast earlier than i do and stop it! the solution is to register a boot receiver. in the receiver start a service which register a sms receiver. since the dynamic receiver has higher priority than than receiver registered statically, you can get the broadcast now.